# Maximizing area of a pentagon

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, algebraic-number-theory, polygons

Suppose $a,b,c,d,e$ are pairwise distinct positive integers. Consider a pentagon with sides $a,b,c,d,e$ and with angles maximizing its area (we assume that a pentagon with such sides exists). It is easy to see that its area $S$ is a positive algebraic number.

What is the smallest possible degree of $S$? Can it be a quadratic irrational? Can it be an integer?

Comment: If the condition "with angles maximizing its area" is "among all pentagons having sides a,b,c,d,e", I think this condition is very difficult to be taken into account, and should be dropped at least in a first step.

Comment: This condition is essential. Because a pentagon with fixed side length is not rigid, its area can change continuously, and is not necessary an algebraic number. In case it is an algebraic number, it can have arbitrarily high or low degree.

Comment: I vaguely remember that the maximum-area polygon with given sides is (?) the one that can be inscribed in a circle; is that true?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: If that were true, it would greatly simplify the problem imho. By the way, the current wording does not forbid $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=10,S=0$ but I guess the OP would want to exclude such degenerate cases.

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, the maximum-area polygon for given sides is cyclic. 
For quadrilateral, it is a consequence of 
[Bretschneider's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula).
For $n$-gon with $n > 4$, one look at any 3 consecutive sides, apply the result for quadrilateral to conclude any 4 consecutive vertices are cyclic. Since any 3 vertices uniquely determine a circle, all vertices of the $n$-gon lie on the same circle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the area $S$ can be an integer.

Given any set of positive numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$.
It is known that among the $n$-gons having this set as side lengths,
the one maximizing the area is cyclic and is unique up to ordering 
of the sides.

Our problem reduces to finding a cyclic pentagon whose side lengths and area are all integers.

Consider the pentagon $ABCDE$ with vertices $A,B,C,D,E$ at:
$$\small
\left(\frac{325}{2},0\right),
\left(\frac{3713}{26},\frac{1008}{13}\right),
\left(-\frac{91}{2},156\right),
\left(-\frac{2047}{26},\frac{1848}{13}\right),
\left(-\frac{2975}{26},-\frac{1500}{13}\right)
$$
This pentagon is cyclic. 
Its vertices lie on a circle centered at origin with radius $\frac{325}{2}$.
In addition, its side lengths and area are all integers:
$$(AB, BC, CD, DE, EA ) = ( 80, 204, 36, 260, 300 )\quad\text{ and }\quad
S = 44160$$

To those who wonder how to find such a pentagon.
The basic idea is working with integers which have multiple inequivalent representation as sum of two squares. If you identify the euclidean plane with the complex plane, 
the vertices of above pentagon have following factorization over Gaussian integers.

$$\begin{cases}
26A &= (1+2i)^2(1-2i)^2(2+3i)^2(2-3i)^2\\
26B &= (1+2i)^4(1-2i)^0(2+3i)^0(2-3i)^4\\
26C &= (1+2i)^0(1-2i)^4(2+3i)^2(2-3i)^2\\
26D &= (1+2i)^4(1-2i)^0(2+3i)^4(2-3i)^0\\
26E &= (1+2i)^2(1-2i)^2(2+3i)^4(2-3i)^0
\end{cases}
$$

**Update**

It turns out this sort of cyclic pentagons with rational side lengths and area has a name! It is known as [Robbins pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_pentagon). It is named after David P. Robbins who had given a formula for the area of a cyclic pentagon as a function of its 
sides${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$.

> Consider a cyclic pentagon with sides $a_1, \ldots, a_5$ and area $S$.
>   If $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_5$ are the symmetric polynomials in the squares of the sides, then $u = 16S^2$ satisfies a degree $7$ condition
>   $$u t_4^3 + t_3^2 t_4^2 - 16 t_3^3 t_5 - 18u t_3 t_4 t_5 - 27 u^2t_5^2 = 0
> \quad\text{ where }\quad
> \begin{cases}
> t_2 &= u − 4\sigma_2 + \sigma_1^2\\
> t_3 &= 8\sigma_3 + \sigma_1 t_2\\
> t_4 &= -64\sigma_4 + t_2^2\\
> t_5 &= 128\sigma_5
> \end{cases}
> $$

A consequence of this is the area $S$ of any cyclic pentagon with integer
sides is algebraic with degree at most $14$.

According to a paper ${}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$ by MacDougall and Buchholz, there are other cyclic pentagons with integer sides and area. Following is a short list for pentagons with $S \le 3000$.

```
peri-
meter   sides        radius  area diagonals
 68 [7,7,15,15,24]     25/2   276 [336/25,20,24,117/5,25]
 72 [7,15,15,15,20]    25/2   342 [20,24,24,25,117/5]
178 [9,20,20,51,78]   325/8  1332 [143/5,504/13,65,1161/25,75]
172 [16,16,25,52,63]   65/2  1638 [2016/65,39,63,253/5,65]
176 [16,25,33,39,63]   65/2  1848 [39,52,60,60,65]
178 [16,25,25,52,60]   65/2  1884 [39,600/13,63,56,836/13]
182 [16,25,33,52,56]   65/2  2058 [39,52,323/5,60,312/5]
182 [25,25,33,39,60]   65/2  2094 [600/13,52,60,63,65]
184 [16,25,39,52,52]   65/2  2148 [39,56,65,312/5,60]
186 [25,33,33,39,56]   65/2  2268 [52,3696/65,60,323/5,837/13]
188 [25,33,39,39,52]   65/2  2358 [52,60,312/5,65,63]
238 [12,12,55,55,104] 325/6  2424 [7752/325,65,1232/13,371/5,100]
218 [13,13,40,68,84]   85/2  2436 [2184/85,51,84,304/5,85]
220 [9,20,51,65,75]   325/8  2760 [143/5,65,406/5,70,78]
220 [20,20,51,51,78]  325/8  2844 [504/13,65,25806/325,75,406/5]
224 [13,36,40,51,84]   85/2  2856 [805/17,68,77,75,85]
224 [9,20,65,65,65]   325/8  2952 [143/5,75,78,78,70]
```

**References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ Robbins, David P. (1994), *Areas of polygons inscribed in a circle*, Discrete and Computational Geometry 12 (2) 223–236
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ MacDougall, James A. and Buchholz, Ralph H. (2008) *Cyclic Polygons with Rational Sides and Area*. Journal of Number Theory, 128 (1). pp. 17-48. ( an online copy can be found [here](http://docserver.carma.newcastle.edu.au/785/) )

Answer (score 1):

If we allow quadratic irrational parameters, we can devise a pentagons with significantly smaller integer sides than the Robbins pentagons. The proposed Pentagon has sides $(a,b,c,d,e,)=(1,2,3,6,7)$ in rotational order.

Begin by specifying a $120°$ angle between the $a$and $b$ sides. Then the diagonal connecting their remote endpoints measures $\sqrt7$ by the Law of Cosines. Similarly, A $120°$ angle between sides $c$ and $d$ gives a diagonal measuring $3\sqrt7=\sqrt{63}$.

Now for the trick. Since the two included angles defined above each measure $120°$, the remaining arc to be bridged by side $e$ subtends an arc also measures $120°$, and so the $\sqrt7$ and $3\sqrt7$ diagonals defined previously which intercept this arc must include an angle of $60°$. The Law of Cosines then gies $e=7$ for the remaining side, as claimed and completing a pentagon with distinct integer sides.

It remains to prove the claim that the curcumradius and area are rational or quadratic-irrational (they will in fact be pure quadratic surds). For the circumradius the $e=$ side is constructed tointercept a $120°$ arc, so the circumradius us $7/\sqrt3=\sqrt{49/3}$. As for tge area, the pentagon consists of three triangles. One has sides $1,2$ with included angle $120°$ contributing an area of $\sqrt3/2$. Another has sides $3,6$ with included angle $120°$, giving an area of $9\sqrt3/2$. The remaining triangle, containing the $e$ side, has its other two sides measuring $\sqrt7$ and $3\sqrt7$, with included angle $60°$; that area is then $21\sqrt3/4$. The total area is then $41\sqrt3/4=\sqrt{5043/16}$.

Comment: Your examples do not have distinct positive integers.