# Maximum area of a pentagon

Tags: geometry

It is given that the lengths of the sides of a pentagon are 3,4,5,6 and 7. What is the largest possible area of the pentagon that can be formed?

Comment: What do you know so far?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829309/maximizing-area-of-a-pentagon/1829556

Comment: I know the solution for the case of a quadrilateral: the area will be maximized when the quadrilateral is cyclic. So I guess the situation maybe similar for the case of a pentagon? But I have no clue how to start with.

Comment: @luimichael According to the link I posted above, that should be true for pentagons as well. As in, the one with the maximum area is cyclic. However I don't know how to find the cyclic pentagon either...

Comment: If that is the case then perhaps check out [Cyclic Pentagon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPentagon.html)

Comment: For any $n > 3$, among all $n$-gon with only side length given, the one maximizing the area is a always cyclic. The basic idea is consider any 3 consecutive sides and show the quadrilateral formed from them is cyclic. Since 3 points determine a cyclic, this force all the quadrilateral constructed this way sharing the same circle and hence all vertices of the $n$-gon maximizing the area lies on that circle.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! For the problem that I asked, how to calculate the maximum area ?

Comment: First, find the circumradius $R$ by solving the equation $\sum_{k=3}^7\sin^{-1}\frac{k}{2R} = \pi$ numerically. Next, compute the area $A$ using the formula $\frac14\sum_{k=3}^7 k\sqrt{4R^2-k^2}$. Even though $A$ is algebraic, it involve 
a polynomial of degree $7$. There doesn't seem to be any way to compute $A$ algebraically.

Answer (score 3):

I have a numerical answer, computed via Maple.

Of all convex pentagons with sides $3,4,5,6,7$, let $P$ be one of largest area.

We know that $P$ must be cyclic.

let $k$ be the area of $P$, and let $r$ be the corresponding radius of the circumscribed circle.

Assuming I've set up the conditions correctly, I get

\begin{align*}
r \approx 4&.3460539586701\\[4pt]
k \approx 41&.1743699363857\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Both $k$ and $r$ are algebraic numbers, hence each satisfies an irreducible polynomial equation with integer coefficients.

I don't yet have such an equation for $k$ (and if I do manage to get one, I'd expect it to be humongous). But I *do* have such an equation for $r$.

The result I obtained is that $r$ is the largest positive real root of the equation

\begin{align*}
&30248483265r^{14}-1927428134940r^{12}+45470450653182r^{10}\\[4pt]
&-434118563895660r^8+51866505172489r^6+29451249855195840r^4\\[4pt]
&-198445569554534400r^2+409754024076902400\\[4pt]
&\!\!= 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1)  $(4k)^2$ will be the root of following septic polynomial: $$u^7-35217u^6+236312613u^5-463271285669u^4+182459512639875u^3\\
+185380558073398125u^2-200219044965753515625u\\
+56928886165176416015625 = 0$$

Comment: Nice going! And the result itself is not as bad looking as I expected.

Comment: Great answer +1, but couldn't the book have chosen sides of $3,3,5,5,7$ instead? That gives a geometrically elegant solution!